# How to use Array in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am a newbie in Ruby. 
I am trying to write a simple interactive game in ruby but am stuck. Need help to proceed. 
Below is the concept:

```
money         = [100, 200, 300, 400]
beneficiaries = ["John", "Sam", "Mary"]
cost1         = [50, 25, 30, 75, 18]
cost2         = [120, 150, 200, 250]
gift1         = [" crayon ", " Pencil ", " Biro "]
gift2         = [" bag ", " shoe ", " Radio "]
cashowned     = [50]
a             = money.sample
b             = cost1.sample
c             = cost2.sample
d             = gift1.sample
e             = gift2.sample
f             = cashowned
puts " Hi, what is your name? "
puts
name = gets.chomp
puts
puts " #{name} is a nice name."
puts
puts "#{name} you have #{f} in your bank account."
puts
puts "Roll the dice and let's see how much you just earned."
puts
gets.chomp.to_i
dice1 = a
puts "#{name} you just earned: #{dice1}"
puts
gets.chomp.to_i
Cashowned = dice1 + f
puts "Your account balance is now : #{cashowned}"
puts
gets.chomp.to_i
```

I am stuck here. I want to repeat/loop the sequence so that I can give out gift at a cost and deduct from cash owned. But cash owned is not updating.
A simpler way to go about this will be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Ruby is a case sensitive language.

Fist you declared your variable as:

```
cashowned = [50]
```

and later you are trying to update using another variable name:

```
Cashowned = dice1 + f
```

note that `"cashowned"` and `"Cashowned"` are different variables

### UPDATE:

Line 7, you have:

```
cashowned = [50]
```

my question is, why not use only:

```
cashowned = 50
```

?

As you are doing will cause the error: `Array can't be coerced into Fixnum (TypeError)`

You are trying to sum a Fixnum with an Array.

See the code:

```
money = [100, 200, 300, 400]
beneficiaries = ["John", "Sam", "Mary"]
cost1 = [50, 25, 30, 75, 18]
cost2 = [120, 150, 200, 250]
gift1 = ["crayon", "Pencil", "Biro"]
gift2 = ["bag", "shoe", "Radio"]
cashowned = 50
a = money.sample
b = cost1.sample
c = cost2.sample
d = gift1.sample
e = gift2.sample
f = cashowned
puts "Hi, what is your name?"
name = gets.chomp
puts "#{name} is a nice name."
puts "#{name} you have #{f} in your bank account."
puts "Roll the dice and let's see how much you just earned."
gets.chomp.to_i
dice1 = a
puts "#{name} you just earned: #{dice1}"
gets.chomp.to_i
cashowned = dice1 + f
puts "Your account balance is now : #{cashowned}"
gets.chomp.to_i
```

And See the test result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that. My main project is ok. I had typos only in the posted question. Still I cant update that variable. It is keeping its first value.

Comment: Ok I give up. Anyone with better idea of how to code this simple game? You roll a dice and you get rewarded from an array that selects the reward at random. Reward will be added to cash owned. Then  at intervals, instead of getting a reward, you get an expense to be deducted from your earnings. The circle keeps going till you reach a predefined maximum figure or bankruptcy. Any help Pls.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update/access value in an array, you need to use index operator

```
cashowned[0] = dice1 + f[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple game I've made. It's not perfect as I've rushed it, but it works and shows you what type of code I think you are asking for. **Pay attention to the *while* loop and *if* statements within the *while* loops.**

```
#set your variables

b = 200 #initial balance
br = -500 #account limit
dice = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

puts "State name?"
n = gets.chomp
puts ""
puts "Greetings #{n}"
puts ""
puts "============================"
puts "Your initial balance is #{b}"
puts "============================"
puts ""
puts "If it reaches or exceeds #{br}"
puts "you'll be declared bankrupt!"
puts ""


while b > br do

#rolling the positive di   
   puts "Roll good di? (y/n)"
   puts ""
        a = gets.chomp.downcase

        if a == "y"
            pd = dice.sample*100
            b += pd 
            puts ""
            puts "****you scored #{pd}****"
            puts "============================"
            puts" new balance: #{b}"
            puts "============================"
            puts ""
        else
            puts "============================"            
            puts "your balance remains at #{b}"
            puts "============================"            
            puts ""
        end


#rolling the negative di  
   puts "Roll evil di? (y/n)"
   puts ""
   ans = gets.chomp.downcase

        if ans == "y"
            nd = dice.sample*-100
            b += nd
            puts ""
            puts "****you scored ****#{nd}****"
            puts "============================"
            puts "new balance: #{b}" 
            puts "============================"
            puts ""
        else
            puts "============================"            
            puts "your balance remains at #{b}"
            puts "============================"            
            puts ""
        end


#option to repeat
   puts ""
   puts "Continue playing (y/n)?"
   puts ""
   ans = gets.chomp.downcase
   puts ""

        if ans == "n" 
            puts ""
            puts "============================"            
            puts "final balance is #{b}"
            puts "============================"            
            puts ""        
            exit

        else
            b
        end

end

puts "You have now reached/exceeded your limit"
puts "of #{br}, so your account has been frozen"
puts ""
```

Run this code and have a look and modify it to suit your needs.